# Scraping two types of URL's

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

In [this page](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/blockify/), under the list of "Dependencies" there are two types of urls. One of them is from the official package site ("https://archlinux.org/packages/") and the other is from the user package website ("https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/"). I want to extract them as a seperate list. According to [this documentation of BeautifulSoup](https://pythonspot.com/extract-links-from-webpage-beautifulsoup/), I came up with something like this so far:

```
sauce = urllib.request.urlopen("https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/blockify/").read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce, 'lxml')
official_dependencies = []
aur_dependencies = []

for h3 in soup.find_all('h3'):
    if "Dependencies" in h3.text:
        for url in h3.find_all_next('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("^https://www.archlinux.org/packages/")}):
            official_dependencies.append(url.get('href'))
```

this works well with my first goal. But I am unsure about how I should extract aur dependencies because their `href` is something like `/packages/package_name/` instead of `https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/package_name/`. And also, there are some aur dependencies written in parenthesis next to official package names. For instance, `alsa-utils (alsa-utils-transparent)`. I want to avoid scraping those alternative aur packages.

I am relatively new to bs4 and do not know regular expressions, so I was a bit confused about how I should be approaching the issue. I would be glad if someone can show me a way to approach the issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's not mandatory for you to stick to bs4, you can try [`lxml.html`](https://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html) solution

```
from lxml import html

response = urllib.request.urlopen("https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/blockify/").read()
source = html.fromstring(response)

all_links = source.xpath('//ul[@id="pkgdepslist"]/li/a/@href')

simple_links = [link for link in all_links if link.startswith('https')]
aur_links = ['https://aur.archlinux.org' + link for link in all_links if not link.startswith('https')]

print(simple_links)
['https://www.archlinux.org/packages/?q=alsa-utils', 'https://www.archlinux.org/packages/?q=gst-python', 'https://www.archlinux.org/packages/?q=pygtk', 'https://www.archlinux.org/packages/?q=python-dbus', 'https://www.archlinux.org/packages/?q=python-docopt', 'https://www.archlinux.org/packages/?q=wmctrl', 'https://www.archlinux.org/packages/?q=python-setuptools', 'https://www.archlinux.org/packages/?q=pulseaudio']

print(aur_links)
['https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/spotify/']
```

Comment: Thank you for your extremely intuitive solution. But one thing is unclear to me. In your code, what avoids aur links that are written in parenthesis that I wanted to avoid?

Comment: @Huzo , those links has `span` node as parent node, so they are not matched by XPath which should be `//ul[@id="pkgdepslist"]/li/span/a/@href` for links in parenthesis

Comment: Ahh I see now. Pardon my HTML knowledge :). Thanks again.